# Error with foodweb package

Tags: r, matrix

I am using `foodweb` package to analyse a bunch of food webs. I keep getting the following error when analyzing a particular food web.

> Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, by.level == 0, value = c(NA_real_,  : 
>     'value' is the wrong length

This is the adyacency matrix for the problematic food web:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0  
1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1  
1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  
1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  
1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  
1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0  
0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0  
1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

There is something wrong with the length, but I can´t figure it out. Any help with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show what code you are actually running. How exactly did you load this data into R?

Comment: I completely forgot to upload my code:  <br/> `web <- read.csv(file = "myweb.csv", header = F)
web <- as.matrix(web)
web

analyse.single(filename = "myweb.csv")`